# Keyboard inputs in c without using a library that does everything for you

Tags: c, windows, input, io, keyboard

I'm working on a 3D Engine for C, and I have (what I believe) to be everything. Except keyboard input, I could use the scanf() function but I imagine that has its problems (like multi-key inputs). I dont want to use a library like SDL2, I just want a header file for inputs or more preferably just getting code to scan for keys and add it to an array or something. Please do not suggest something better or a library that would do everything for me, I want to build this from scratch. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to process the following two window messages in your [message loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues):

- [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown)
- [`WM_KEYUP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keyup)

See the [Microsoft documentation on Keyboard Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/keyboard-input) for further information.

Comment: Could you give me an example on how to implement this? I am very new to C so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @Uperscuzzi: Here is a link to the [official Microsoft tutorial on how to make programs that handle keyboard input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/keyboard-input). If you have trouble understanding this tutorial, then you may need to first do the tutorials in [Module 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program) which teach you how to handle Window messages. Note that this tutorial references C++, but as far as I can tell, it all also applies to C.